# Hibernate - XML Mapping of a N<->N Table with extra columns

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, pojo

I have this schema:

```
---------------  --------------------  ----------------
| Customers   |  | CustomRoutePrice |  | Route        |
|-------------|  |------------------|  ---------------|
| CustId (pk) |  | CustId  (pk)     |  | RouteId (pk) |
| Desc        |  | RouteId (pk)     |  | Desc         |
---------------  | Price            |  | Price        |
                 --------------------  ----------------
```

and I want to map the `CustomRoutePrice`'s Price to my `Customer`s POJO, saying something like:

```
Map<Route, Double> customRoutesPrices;
```

or maybe having a new POJO called `CustomRoute`, so it may look something like this:

```
public class CustomRoute {
    private Customer customer;
    private Route route;
    private Double price;
}
```

so within my `Customer`s POJO I could have a set like:

```
Set<CustomRoute> customRoutes;
```

which may be the set of `CustomRoute`s for that `Customer`.

So my question is how can I make possible both mappings?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare a Map<Route,Double>:

```
<map name="customRoutesPrices" table="CustomRoutePrice">
  <key column="CustId" not-null="true"/>
  <map-key-many-to-many class="Route" column="RouteId"/>
  <element column="Price" type="double"/>
</map>
```

Comment: Thank you! I've done that, but instead of <map-key-many-to-many/> I used <map-key/>. I'm new on this!

Comment: But, how about if I want to use a `Set<CustomRoute>`?? how could I map that POJO?

Comment: You would need to map the class CustomRoute with a compound key. Ken Chan's post have a link to an example of such a structure.

Answer (score 0):

It is the classical example of many-to-many mapping where the association table has extra columns besides the PK of both many sides. [Here](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/) shows a complete example for this type of mapping