# Hibernate How to add a column in a middle table

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Here's the details.

I have 2 entity tables with one to many relationship.

First, `Exam` class has many `Category` class. Hibernate generates this tables

```
______________
Exam
- Id
- Name 
- Category
______________
Category
- Id
- Name
______________
Exam_Category
- Exam_Id
- Category_Id
```

I need to add an extra column in `Exam_Category` table
ex:

```
______________
Exam_Category
- Exam_Id
- Category_Id
* User_Id
```

How am i going to accomplish this. if ever, how will i also get the `user_id` value because the `Exam_Category` is not exposed. Thanks

Comment: Why you have an extra table, when you don't have a `many-to-many` relationship?

Comment: You could use a Map<Category,User> field in your Exam class. See [this post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179538/hibernate-xml-mapping-of-a-n-n-table-with-extra-columns/7187557#7187557

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use a collection of elements.

```
@Entity
public class Exam {
    @CollectionOfElements(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "EXAM_CATEGORY", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FK_EXAM"))
    public Set<CategoryEntry> getCategories() {
        return this.categories;
    }
}

@Embeddable
public class CategoryEntry{

    private Category category;
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_CATEGORY", nullable = false)
    public Category getCategory() {
        return this.category;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_USER", nullable = false)
    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

// ... setters and such

}

@Entity
public class Category {
}
```

This approach is cleaner than mapping it as an entity, since, logically, it is not an entity to begin with.

Then you can add some other methods in `Exam` to get all the categories (without the users) or to retrieve it as a map, or whatever.  You can completely hide this intermediate object through encapsulation, if that is required.

Comment: i think this is great, but I'm not using annotations. I'll try this though when I change our app to annotations. Many Thanks..

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, but I think all of Hibernate's functionality is also available through mapping xmls.  I suppose you could do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is the case of many-to-many relationship with three tables (three foreign keys) involved. This cannot be achieved in Hibernate by simple mapping. You will have to extend your definition of Entity classes to support custom primary key column on the "middle" table·

Check out [this](http://www.dantoomeysoftware.com/pencils-down/2008/12/29/how-to-use-hibernate-for-composite-ids-and-many-to-many-mappings/) reference.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Map field in your Exam class. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179538/hibernate-xml-mapping-of-a-n-n-table-with-extra-columns/7187557#7187557)